Specific nouns with zero article
I asked the AI to write a short text about going to a football game, using simple language. We had no previous discussion and I never mentioned anything about learning english or grammar.

Yesterday, I went to watch a football game. First, I bought tickets
online. Then, I went to the stadium. Many people were already there,
chatting and eating snacks. I found my seat and sat down. Players were
warming up on the field. The referee blew the whistle to start the
game. The crowd cheered loudly. During the game, players passed
the ball to each other

Do you have any ideas why they used "players" with the zero article twice, when they are obviously talking about the specific players who took part in this football game.The noun is well-established in the context and well-defined. Further in the text the AI actually started using "the players", but these 2 cases puzzle me.
According to my research when a thing is strongly expected to be present, we have to use "the" before it. Like when I am talking about my visit to a restaurant, I have to use "the waiters" (the ones that work there), unless I want to emphasize their class/role.

"I arrived at the restaunt, the waiters were serving the tables"

Problem is, I asked the AI to write some similar stories but on different topics and such pattern keeps appearing very often: a specific plural noun, very-well defined by the context, but having zero article.
I assume the AI is right and It is me who doesn't understand some subtle nuances of article usage. Is that true, is the AI right to use articles like that?

You really shouldn't use current AI's to teach idiomatic use of English. There's nothing wrong with having no article before players in the cited text - it's just a "less common stylistic choice". But it's pointless speculating why the AI did that, since it doesn't actually have a reason (it's not trying to impart any particular nuance, such as might be the case if we were analysing text known to come from a competent and careful writer).

"The players" sounds more natural in both instances. Just using "players" sounds as if you're talking to someone that doesn't know that football has players.

I stand to be corrected, but I thought all Stack Exchange sites are currently supposed to immediately reject out of hand any questions primarily based on something from an AI.

@YonKuma: Don;t overstate the case for the article. It's easy to find plenty of written instances of the sequence "down waiters were" in Google Books. Where I only included down because that's likely to be from a preceding sentence ending with sat down, so any matches will almost certainly be starting a new sentence with "un-articled" waiters as the subject.

In this particular context I think "the players" would be more idiomatic in both instances. Usually the zero article is used with plural nouns to talk about general situations, rather than anything specific (like a particular set of players at a specific football match). That's not to say it's grammatically wrong. It's just less likely, less idiomatic, or even slightly odd to use it in a context like this.  As to why the AI did this, you'd have to ask the programmers. Maybe they aren't training it on well written sources. Who knows!

I’m voting to close this question because it's about artificial intelligence, as opposed to English language.

Thank you everyone! I was convinced that the AI's speech was supposed to be equal to that of a native speaker, at least in terms of grammar. You really opened my eyes and thanks for making it clear that both options are acceptable, with the "the" being the most idiomatic one

"During the game, [the] players passed the ball to each other" there is nothing wrong with this sentence. The article before players  is optional. Adding a third "the" in that short sentence is a question of style or personal choice.

"Players" without an article would make sense if it was some of the players; "the players" might imply all the players. Although omitting the article does rather imply that passing the ball is incidental to the game. It might be better to use "some of the players" or "all of the players" if you want to be clear; the passage isn't very natural.

Although I think it's foolish to ask why a machine failed, I could imagine the same text being written by a human, so let's examine when it might be appropriate. You say:

According to my research when a thing is strongly expected to be present, we have to use "the" before it

The problem might be that you instructed the AI to "use simple language," so it explained as it might to someone with no prior understanding of football. (Or it did so inconsistently; surely the concept of "referee" takes more explanation than "players.") But the point stands: when you're introducing new concepts, things that are "strongly expected" might not yet be expected by your audience, so you might skip the "the" when you introduce them for the first time (and hopefully, explain them a bit better), and then include the article in future mentions.
Let's try to do a better job than the AI, using the referee:

A football game has rules. Referees are there to make sure these rules are followed. During the game, the referee moves around the field with the players and watches them closely.


that's an interesting theory and I like your answer, but In reality, I've been testing the AI's usage of articles for weeks now and the AI has been very inconsistent. Unfortunately it's my only option for my research because I don't have a native speaker I can ask dozens of questions a day. Overall, the AI is using articles correctly until you start questioning if the usage is correct. After that it goes into panic mode and keeps changing its opinion constantly.

Articles are not always used with plurals.

"There was a fight and shirts were torn, vs. "There was a fight and a shirt was torn."
"There are raisins in my cereal," vs. "There is a raisin in my cereal."
"Flags were waved," vs. "A flag was waved."

Yes, you could say, "The flags were waved," but it's optional.
As for AI, that is a programming question, not one on English usage.
